# LibreOffice : how shall I change the names of the weekdays in date format

Tags: date, format, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In LibreOffice, I wish to change the weekdays names to have something shorter.
In French, the date format "ddd dd/mm/yy" applied to today 2021-08-17 gives : "mar. 17/08/21". I would prefer "ma 17/08/21" to have narrower columns.

So I wish to change the existing weekdays names "lun., mar., mer., jeu., even., sam., dim." to something shorter : "lu, ma, me, je, ve, sa, di", through the format used by LibreOffice.

I played with French locales (Swiss French, etc.) but it is not satisfactory. I tried to change the list for the sort but it has no effect on the date format.

Is it possible to change the list LibreOffice uses for the weekdays ? How shall I proceed ?

Comment: You might like to check some of [the text functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.4/Calc/Text_Functions/fr).

Comment: @the busy bee : I wish to do it through the format because I have numerous date to display and I don't want to weigh down my sheet

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with normal formatting (unless you require a change to the national date standard).

However, you can easily get the desired date representation using the [**TEXTE()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/fr/text/scalc/01/04060110.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3147132) and [**REGEX()**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/fr/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html) functions.

`=REGEX(TEXT(A1;"OOO JJ/MM/AA");"(..)([^\.]*\.)(.+)";"$1$3";"g")`

Or shorter notation using LEFT() (GAUCHE()):

`=LEFT(TEXT(A1;"OOO");2)&TEXT(A1;"\ JJ/MM/AA")`

Remember to check that the cell format is French, otherwise you will get an error (not every language uses O-J-A characters)

[image: SetFr]

Comment: thanks for your detailed and interesting solution including the regex() function I didn't know of, coming from the Excel world. However, I have numerous days and I don't want to weigh down my sheet. That's the reason I want to change the format only. I am ready to change the national date standard if necessary but I don't know how.

Comment: Oh no! Changing the national standard is too difficult. Better to consider alternative options. For example, leave the date "as is", day / month / year, and designate the day of the week not with letters, but, for example, with color - the WEEKDAY() function in conditional formatting will paint Saturday-Sunday red, Monday-Tuesday and Thursday-Friday in white, and the Wednesday ​in blue (or any other colorization option)